# How to solve "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed"..?

Tags: java, spring-boot, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am getting below exception while deployment of WAR file on Weblogic Server 12 c.I have used spring and hibernate framework

Below is error log :

```
 ####<Oct 9, 2018 3:28:48,379 AM EDT> <Error> <Deployer> <localhost.localdomain> <ocgw_1> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <07b6cea3-ccdf-4e9e-836f-b86fdf0ed2a3-0000014f> <1539070128379> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "987906058076027" for task "7" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    ................
    ................
    ................
Caused By: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:686)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:315)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:240)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:223)
    at com.oracle.classloader.JarURLHandler.openConnection(JarURLHandler.java:118)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:979)
    at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:168)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
    ...................
    ...................
    ...................
```

Why I am getting this error while deploying war files

Any help would be appreciated..
Thanks

Comment: refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19123887/jetty-java-lang-illegalstateexception-zip-file-closed